# Check if ID from a table exists in another table, and if so, how many times

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have two tables

Table a

*some_ID*
1
2
3
4

Table b

*some_ID*
1
2
1
4

Now what I would like to receive is a table like

*id* *amount*

1     |   2
2 | 1

I tried with a following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.some_id) as id  
            FROM Table_a  
            INNER JOIN Table_b  
            ON Table_a.some_id = Table.b.some_id
```

but that only returned how many id rows there are in both tables.
Any help?

Comment: Your logic is a little unclear.  What does the result set mean?

Comment: I'm trying to check if each ID in table A exists in table B and if it does, how many times. In my bad result table ID 1 was found two times in the table B and the ID 2 once. So on the left is the ID and on the right the amount of times it shows up in the B table.

Comment: @Eckersley Shouldn't the result in your example also include ID 4 - Cnt 1 ?

Comment: Yeah it should, missed it by accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the zero counts:

```
SELECT a.some_id AS id, count(b.some_id) as amount
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.some_id = b.some_id
GROUP BY a.some_id
```

Result:

```
id | amount  
 1 |  2  
 2 |  1  
 3 |  0  
 4 |  1
```

If not:

```
SELECT a.some_id AS id, count(*) as amount
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.some_id = b.some_id
GROUP BY a.some_id
```

Result:

```
id | amount  
 1 |  2  
 2 |  1  
 4 |  1
```

The difference is the join type. Once left outer join. Then inner join. Note that in the first case it is important to count with `count(b.some_id)`. With `count(*)` the rows with missing b entries would be counted as 1. `count(*)` counts the rows. `count(expression)` counts the non-null values.

Answer (score 2):

Do the grouping on table_b and then join that result set on table_a

```
SELECT b.* FROM 
(
  SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM Table_b
  GROUP BY id
) b
INNER JOIN Table_a a ON a.id = b.id
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d5a07/1)**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a histogram of histograms:

```
select cnt, count(*) as num_ids
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from b
      group by id
     ) b
group by cnt;
```